# Exactly one pact source should be set

Tags: pact

I am writing pact testing for provider.
I have written a class. While running as JUNIT , i am getting exception,
"Exactly one pact source should be set"" 
Could you please help ?

this is my code..

```
@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("personlisation-service")
@PactFolder("/pacts")
@PactUrl(urls = {"file:///pacts/PersonalisationServiceContractTest-CourierProfileController.json"})
@IgnoreNoPactsToVerify
@PactBroker(host = "${pact.broker.host:pact.hermescloud.co.uk}",
            port = "${pact.broker.port:443}",
            protocol = "${pact.broker.protocol:https}",
            tags = "${pactbroker.tags:master}")
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = Application.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = {.....
 }
      )

public class CourierProfilePactProviderTestIT {
--------
.
..
....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've specified both @PactBroker and @PactUrl. Both of these are flags to tell the framework where to fetch pacts from. You should use just one of these (probably the broker in most cases)